# How to move an image in css/html/js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a game where you use the arrow keys to move left, right, jump, and roll.

My HTML is below so far, very empty because of how stuck I am. I have not yet found an image but will put that matter in my own hands *after I am done with this*.

```css
html {
  background: url("Game_city.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

img {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#imgcole {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: opx;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <span id="pos"></span>
  <img id="imgcole" src="" alt="cole" style:width="300px" , height="300px">
</center>
```

I have found a way to do this with a square drawn with the canvas element (https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_controllers_keys)
but since I don't know javascript, I couldn't figure out how to change the code accordingly to my code. The actual website I am coding's link is here, press the play button, then chose the guy with the hammer:https://ninjago-game-of-masks.ayushgudipati.repl.co/

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing, I just started learning to code and am only 13. Any suggestion is helpful, thanks!

Comment: What you can do is add specific classes which moves the image on every click of a button, but can you explain clearly what do you want so I can explain in better language

Comment: I am trying, in the long run, to make a game that is something like this [game, so I need to move the image.](https://beinternetawesome.withgoogle.com/en_us/interland/landing/tower-of-treasure). I am talking about the part where you run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you're trying to go about this, I'm assuming you haven't attempted to implement the movement yet? But if you`re trying to avoid frameworks I would suggest using javascript events:
[https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HerCR8bw_GE&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Zy51Q-x9tMWIv9cueOFTFA)
This is a way to get input from the user and have it dynamically manipulate the DOM (change things in your program like moving an image). This isnt a full solution on how to implement this, but more of a push in the right direction. If you just want to make a game, using a Javascript framework such as p5.js makes this a lot easier.
If you want to learn about that Coding Train on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HerCR8bw_GE&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Zy51Q-x9tMWIv9cueOFTFA has a ton of tutorials on this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, as per your code view, and you will get result, and try to use larger image, like 1920*1080, or something like this, so that whole page will be covered.

```
body
{
   padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("bg2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```